# read the txt file and save into table sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have a txt file and my txt file has a 27000000 and i want read this file and save in sql server table 
i use this sql server `T-SQL`:

```
BULK
INSERT Employee
FROM 'E:\\file.txt' --location with filename
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

and my file is:

```
66200 6827           435200 1393/05/23 14:26:26     18      1
66200 6819           435200 1393/05/23 14:28:45    113      1
```

but my file structure is:

```
66200<space>6827<space space>435200<space>1393/05/23<space space>14:26:26<space space space>18      
66200<space>6819<space space>435200<space>1393/05/23<space space>14:28:45<space space space>113      <br>
```

in the bulk block i write this field terminator:

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
```

and my file evry time has a two space character and every time has a third character.and bulk not work
but i want to read this file.
how can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you replace all occurence of double spaces with single space? Is there any restriction?

Comment: how can i replace 27000000 records?

Comment: Find and replace u tried and failed is it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a format file something like this....

```
10.0
6
1       SQLINT        0       4       " "      1     Col1         ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       100     "  "     2     Col2         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR       0       100     " "      3     Col3         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR       0       100     "  "     4     Col4         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR       0       100     "    "   5     Col5         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR       0       100     "\r\n"   6     Col6         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Save the file as `.fmt` , Replace the Col1, Col2, Col3..... with the actual column names in your table.

Then you would write your Insert statement something like ...

```
BULK INSERT Employee
FROM 'E:\file.txt'    --location with filename
WITH
    (
     FORMATFILE = 'E:\Format_file.fmt'  --path to your format file. 
    );
```

Comment: thanks to pay attention my problem,but i have a error

Comment: Msg 4862, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "d:\format.fmt" is incomplete or could not be read. Operating system error code (null).

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  My guess is that it's failing because you have seven columns and the format file only specifies six.  Add a definition for that final "1".